# AsyncTask runs twice

Tags: android, android-asynctask, datetimepicker

I am using AsyncTask in one of my activity. I am using a datetime fragment to get date as user input and then based on that input AsyncTask runs and a service is called. Every this works fine. But main problem is that AsyncTask runs two times. When I click the button datetimefragment open and after selecting the date AsyncTask is called.

```
public class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            now=Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = now.get(Calendar.DATE);
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            datetime = year+checkDigit(month+1)+checkDigit(day);
            AsyncWSCH call_history  = new AsyncWSCH();
            call_history.execute();
        }
        public String checkDigit(int number)
        {
            return number<=9?"0"+number:String.valueOf(number);
        }
    }
```

This is button click event.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}
else{
 do something else.
}
```

can anyone help in pointing the issue where I am making a mistake and why below two lines of co

```
AsyncWSCH call_history  = new AsyncWSCH();
 call_history.execute();
```

Comment: You don't have @override before onDataSet. I believe you should have, unless you have missed to copy it somehow...

Edit:wording

Comment: You need to clean up the question.  You stated that it runs twice but not that it is a bad thing.  Do you not want it to run at both places?  Also your last sentence at the end is cut off

Comment: @Rick I want to Asynctask to run only One time. however in above code these AsyncWSCH call_history  = new AsyncWSCH();
            call_history.execute(); this codes runs twice. 
last sentence is below two lines of code are running twice. Sorry for it

Comment: Did Greg's answer not work?  It looks like when you open the picker it checks the onDateSet which runs the code then again when you pick the date. Greg is saying check to see if the date when it opens is the same at the time its opened then don't do anything.  Else run your code.

Comment: @Rick 
On Greg code dt.getTime() is not available

Comment: he just updated his code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onDateSet` is getting called twice.

Replace it with this:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        String dt = year+checkDigit(month+1)+checkDigit(day);
        if (!dt.equals(datetime)) {
            datetime = dt;
            AsyncWSCH call_history  = new AsyncWSCH();
            call_history.execute();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code says Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Date
on Date dt = year+checkDigit(month+1)+checkDigit(day);
and 
The method getTime() is undefined for the type String
on if (dt.getTime() != datetime.getTime())

Comment: I can't see what type it should be. I updated my answer since it is apparently a string.

Answer (score 0):

It's an Android bug, `onDataSet` is called twice: the first time when the user accepts the date, the second time when the dialog is dismissed. You could handle it with a boolean.